# vpermil2ps и Flat Assembler

Tags: ассемблер, fasm, sse

Компиляция в Fasm
vpermil2ps xmm1,xmm2,xmm3,xmm4,5
выдаёт код C4 E3 68 48 CB 45 вместо C4 E3 **69** 48 CB 45

Есть ли в Fasm директива кодировки AVX, наподобие OPTION AVXENCODING в MASM?

Comment: Документация AMD (43479.pdf Revision Date 3.04 November 2009)
    (VPERMIL2PS xmm1, xmm2, xmm3/mem128, xmm4, imm8 C4 RXB.03 0.^xsrc1.0.00 48 /r imm8)
Расшифровка части кода  [0.^xsrc1.0.00  -->  W.vvvv.L.pp]
Документация AMD (26568.pdf Revision Date 3.25 November 2021)
    (VPERMIL2PS xmm1, xmm2, xmm3/mem128, xmm4, m2z C4 RXB.03 0.^src1.0.01 48 /r is5)
Расшифровка  [0.^src1.0.01  -->   W.vvvv.L.pp]
            В 2009 году код заканчивается на 00 (поле pp), а в 2021 уже 01 (поле pp). Странно! Возможно в этом причина. (^ - инверсия) Видно плохо, извините, не знаю как поправить.

Comment: Вот ещё на форуме обсуждение https://wasm.in/threads/novye-xop-instrukcii-vpermil2ps-i-vpermil2pd.29906/